# Привилегии в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, users

Как реализовать привилегии в django. Например у нас есть vip и premium. Надо сделать так, чтобы пользователь с vip или premium мог читать часть текста в посте, а обычный нет. При этом есть еще один пост где vip и пользователь не могут там читать, но premium может. Как это реализовать и пожалуйста можно пример =D

Comment: Хотелось бы сперва увидеть попытку или даже мысли по поводу реализации) Можете на досуге глянуть на эту [документацию](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Comment: Я думал на счет Permissions, проблема в том что у меня одна модель поста и если мы выдадим пользователю vip, то ему будут доступны все посты. Тогда есть вариант разделить на три модели пост для обычного пользователя, vip и premium. Я думаю как реализовать все с одной моделью. Если я думаю не правильно подправьте меня!

Comment: у вас на шаблонах сделано или АПИ должен возвращать данные?